# UWP Navigating to Page of same type

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, windows-10, viewmodel

I have a `Page` called `TableView` that is used for adding/editing/deleting records in the application's database. Instead of creating a specific `TableView` page for each model class, I decided to make `TableView` more generic by just passing it the appropriate `TableViewModel` for whatever type of object I am editing.

For example, if I want to work with `Foo` objects I would say something like:

`Frame.Navigate(typeof(TableView), new FooTableViewModel());`

This seemed to work pretty well, until I started working with child entities.

For example, if one `Foo` had many `Bars`, I can use `TableView` to navigate to a new `TableView` showing all `Bar` entities attached to the selected `Foo` entity. For example:

`Frame.Navigate(typeof(TableView), new BarTableViewModel(selectedFooId));`

The problem occurs when I click the back button while viewing `Bar` entities to go back to the base `Foo` entity. I noticed the entire page was getting reloaded every time which is not exactly ideal.

At first, I thought I simply needed to setup caching on `TableView` like so:

`this.NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;`

However, this seems to break the setup entirely since the caching seems to be done by type, and there is only one type of `TableView` Page. Therefore, when I attempt to view a child entity and navigate to another `TableView` with a different View Model, I end up going nowhere because there is already a `TableView` cached.

Being new to UWP, its possible that my original idea of using just one `TableView` and passing it different View Models was not a good idea in the first place.  Is there anyway that I can use this current setup but still take advantage of UWP navigation and page caching?  Should I be going about this a different way entirely?

Comment: You described your question in detail, but you'd better upload a [mcve] here. I believe there're no community members will be happy to make a code sample to test for you by your description.

Comment: i am currently facing this same exact problem. Did you manage to resolve your issue?

Comment: @MarkB We ended up making unique views for every page we needed, and nesting a common page inside of each view. For example we have FooTableView, and BarTableView and inside of each of those we embedded a standard TableView page that had all of the common functionality.